Test google cloud function using postman - 500 error
I have this code in a google cloud function
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { Buffer } = require('buffer')
//const busboy = require('busboy')
const crypto = require('crypto')
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true})

//fix encrypting e decrypting file multipli
const processBase64Input = async (password, base64Files) => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        const salt = crypto.randomBytes(32)
        const key = crypto.scryptSync(password, salt, 32)
        const processed = []
        base64Files.forEach( (base64) => {
            const output = []
            const iv =  crypto.randomBytes(16);
            const cipher =  crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv);
            const encryptedData = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(base64, 'utf8'), cipher.final()]);
            const data = `${iv.toString('hex')}:${encryptedData.toString('hex')}`;
            console.log('const data log\n', data)
            output.push(data);
            const result = output.join(' '); 
            console.log('const result log\n', result)
            processed.push(`${salt.toString('hex')}+${result}`)
        });
        resolve(processed)
    })
}

//
exports.encryptFiles = functions.https.onRequest( (req, res) => {
    cors( req, res, async () => {
        console.log(req.body.password, req.body.base64Files)
        
        let password = req.body.password
        let base64Files =  req.body.base64Files

        let output = []
        let salt = crypto.randomBytes(32)
        let key = crypto.scryptSync(password, salt, 32)

        base64Files.forEach( (base64) => {
            console.log('processing base64: ', base64)
            let iv =  crypto.randomBytes(16);
            let cipher =  crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv);
            let encryptedData = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(base64.file, 'utf8'), cipher.final()]);
            let data = `${iv.toString('hex')}:${encryptedData.toString('hex')}`;
            output.push({
                fileName: base64.fileName,
                encryptedFile: `${salt.toString('hex')}+${data}`
            })
            console.log(output)
        })

        res.send(output)
        //res.send("Hello from Firebase!");
    })
});

//
exports.decryptFiles = functions.https.onRequest( (req, res) => {
    cors( req, res, () => {
        let encryptedFiles =  req.body.encryptedFiles
        let password = req.body.password
        let output = [];

        encryptedFiles.forEach( (file) => {
            let [salt, fileContents] = file.split('+');
            let key = crypto.scryptSync(password, Buffer.from(salt, 'hex'), 32);
            let splittedFile = fileContents.split(' ');
            output = splittedFile.map( (file) => {
              let [iv, content] = file.split(':');
              let cipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, Buffer.from(iv, 'hex'));
              let decryptedData = cipher.update(content, 'hex', 'utf8');
              return decryptedData;
            });
        })
        res.send(output)
    })
})

In postman I'm inserting the url of the cloud function and then I go to the body tab and set the multipart form data and the two key I need, in my case the first key that is password and the second key that is base64Files, for this field I select the file option and I open the file selector to select a file to encrypt. I did not set the content type, after this I then click the send request button of postman and I get the error.
The function will not detect the password field. How I can correctly test the function using postman? I have two functions, one is for encrypt files and another is for decrypt. any help?

Please edit the question to show what you're doing that doesn't work the way you expect.  There should be enough information for someone to copy what you have and use it to reproduce the same result.  It's not clear what you mean by "the function will not detect the password field".
